# How to restore file permissions, to their default. Following chmod -R 777 /

Tags: permissions

Basically i entered a wrong command on one of my most important cpanel server
chmod -R 777 /
And all the folders and files are changed to 777 permission and all the services like phpmyadmin and mail services has been stop no idea due to high permission.
Can anyone suggest that how i can restore the permission of each files and folder to the default one.

Comment: This _may_ be doable, but probably not on files that are not under package management. It would depend on what Linux you are using.

Comment: If the distro is rpm based, you could use rpm --setperms <packagename>

Answer (score -2):

There is no magic procedure, the only way to restore it would be manually.

Fortunatelly the procedure is easy, but it should have to be performed carefully

**Step 1:**
Copy the following script, paste it on your console to generate fixpermission script

> echo ' chmod -R 755 /bin /boot /dev /etc/ /home /lib /lib64 \ /media
>   /mnt /opt /run /sbin /srv /usr /var
>
> chmod -R 777 /initrd.img /vmlinuz chmod -R 1777 /tmp chmod -R 555 /sys
>   chmod -R 555 /proc chmod -R 700 /root
>
> ' > fixpermission
>
> chmod +x fixpermission
>
> ./fixpermission

The above will create a script named fixpermission and run it by ./fixpermission if not already invoked.

**Step 2:**
**Run stat -c '%A %a %n' /*** to show your proper directory and their permission as restored.

**Example**: Your directory permission structure should look similar to the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x 755 /bin 
drwxr-xr-x 755 /boot
drwxr-xr-x 755 /dev
drwxr-xr-x 755 /etc
drwxr-xr-x 755 /home
lrwxrwxrwx 777 /initrd.img
lrwxrwxrwx 777 /initrd.img.old
drwxr-xr-x 755 /lib
drwxr-xr-x 755 /lib64
drwx------ 700 /lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 755 /media
drwxr-xr-x 755 /mnt
drwxr-xr-x 755 /opt
dr-xr-xr-x 555 /proc
drwx------ 700 /root
drwxr-xr-x 755 /run
drwxr-xr-x 755 /sbin
drwxr-xr-x 755 /srv
dr-xr-xr-x 555 /sys
drwxrwxrwt 1777 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x 755 /usr
drwxr-xr-x 755 /var
lrwxrwxrwx 777 /vmlinuz
lrwxrwxrwx 777 /vmlinuz.old
```

***Information source:***

https://askubuntu.com/questions/958141/fix-permissions-of-server-after-accidental-chmod/958189#958189

Comment: Edited for a deeper explanation referencing the original source in the final.

Comment: This solution make files that should not be user-readable like `/etc/shadow` or `/etc/sudoers` readable and does not restore suid/sgid permissions on programs that need them (say `/usr/bin/passwd`). This procedure does not give you a working system.